# Apache cordova / phonegap how to enable capabilities from config.xml

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I have an application that uses some ios capabilities (Keychain sharing, Push notifications, etc)

Every time that it remove the platforms and re-run cordova platform add ios, I have to manually open the XCode and open the settings .xcodeproj and go to the Capabilities tab and enable them manually.

Is there any way to auto enable them automatically every time that I re-run cordova platform add ios?

Thanks

Comment: Were you able to solve your problem? If yes can you please post the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You may not need to do this at all.

Features you mentioned (Keychain sharing, Push notifications) will work without manually enabling the associated capabilities in XCode if the plugins you use add the required entitlements on install.

And most well-developed plugins do just that. For example:

- If you use [phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push) for push notifications:
  it [adds the required `aps-environment` key to `Entitlements-*.plist`
  automatically](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/commit/e6013d49ecf0025be10fb6bb87152ee4025b5df4)
- If you use [Telerik-Verified-Plugins/Keychain-Sharing](https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/Keychain-Sharing) for Keychain sharing: it does too [install entitlements](https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/Keychain-Sharing/blob/master/src/ios/hooks/install_entitlements.js) via a Cordova hook

Simply make sure you're using a recent-enough version of the plugin in question.

Comment: Why the downvote? Please post a comment with a reason, let's solve whatever problem you have with this solution. Because I did use this in production and it worked (even though these capabilities are displayed as disabled in XCode UI, the build and the app works as expected, because the plist gets modified properly by the plugin hooks)

Comment: downvote because it doesn't answer the exact question